# Disable OK button in alert

Tags: javascript, jsp, alert

Is there any way to disable 'Ok' button of alert in java script?

I have a java script function which calls two different window , the second window pop up is delayed by an alert as I need to open it after some operation is complete in the first window opened . I need to disable the alert till some operation in complete in first window. Please suggest some way.

Below is the js function(myFunction()) which is called on a button click an opens two window :

```
    function myFunction() {
        myFunction2();
        alert("Please wait...");
        myFunction1();
    }

    function myFunction2() {
        var x ="sce";
        var URL ="Multiple.jsp?viewStatus="+x;
        var windowName = "showDeb";
          var width  = screen.availWidth;
          var height = screen.availHeight;
          var w = 900;
          var h =   500;
          var features =
            'width='          + w +
            ',height='        + h +
            ',left='          + ((width - w - 10) * .5)  +
            ',top='           + ((height - h - 30) * .5) +
            ',directories=no' +
            ',location=no'    +
            ',menubar=no'     +
            ',scrollbars=yes' +
            ',status=no'      +
            ',toolbar=no'     +
            ',resizable=false';

           var strOpen = window.open (URL, windowName, features);
           strOpen.focus();
           myFunction1();
    }
    function myFunction1() {
        var x ="deb";
        var URL ="Multiple.jsp?viewStatus="+x;
        var windowName = "showSce";
           var width  = screen.availWidth;
           var height = screen.availHeight;
           var w = 900;
           var h =  500;
           var features =
               'width='          + w +
               ',height='         + h +
               ',left='       + ((width - w - 10) * .5)  +
               ',top='            + ((height - h - 30) * .5) +
               ',directories=no' +
               ',location=no'     +
               ',menubar=no'      +
               ',scrollbars=yes' +
               ',status=no'   +
               ',toolbar=no'      +
               ',resizable=false';

            var strOpen = window.open (URL, windowName, features);
            strOpen.focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use cookies to communicate between your windows.
In window 1 set cookie once process is completed.

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate()+1); 
document.cookie = "name=win1; path=/; expires="+date.toGMTString()
```

In parent file which will open window 2, add timer to wait until window 1 sets cookie.

```
   var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000); // Poll every second to check if window 1 has completed its execution by checking cookie.
   function myTimer() {
      var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

      for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        if (cookies[i].trim() == "name=win1") {
          // stop timer and open win 2
          clearTimeout(myVar);
          document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML = "Process in window 1 completed";

         // <<< Open window 2 here >>>

          var dateNow = new Date();
          document.cookie = "name=win1; path=/; expires="+dateNow.toGMTString();
        }
      }
```

Make sure that you delete the cookie before window one is opened and after window 2 is opened else it will cause issue in re-run as cookie will be already present before window 1 completes the process.
To delete the cookie just set expiry date as current time or privious.

```
var dateNow = new Date();
document.cookie = "name=win1; path=/; expires="+dateNow.toGMTString();
```

Here is an example which demonstrates the same. Make sure you allow pop up as it will try to open new window.
http://embed.plnkr.co/MVa45iwYuW9asQuYRzBV/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion . But I have one query , what I understood from the above is  I can use this way if I know the time required to complete the process in window 1 . In my case the time is not fixed it can be more based on the data

Comment: You don't need to know the time required to complete the process in window 1. As you said the process running in window 1 is based on data, you will need to set cookie once the process is completed.
The timer in parent which opens window 2 will be polling every second (configurable) to check if cookie is set or not for infinite time until window 1 sets the cookie. 
You can also keep time out (like 30 mins) in case  if you want to stop polling in parent for infinite time.